# Regression with Logistic / Count Data

Tags: regression, logistic, poisson-distribution, count-data

I have data from an experiment that I'm trying to figure out what to do with, I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance.

Each experimental subject is from one of two groups, 'A' or 'B'. Each subject runs through a series of trials, labelled "t_1" to "t_30". For each trial, the subject is given information and chooses either "true" or "false".

My hypothesis is that subjects from group 'B' are more likely to choose "true" than subjects from group 'A' are, and I need to find a way test this hypothesis. It should be noted that there are inherent differences between trials (t_1 to t_30) that make everyone more or less likely to pick "true" for one trial compared to another, so I would like to account for the trial number as some sort of random effect.

I tried a mixed logistic regression for this, something like:

```
choose_true ~ group + (group | trial)
```

But the model had a pseudo-R^2 of something around 0.002 which is clearly an awful model. I could look at this a different way, as "count" data (i.e. each subject picks "true" on X number of trials), not sure what to do with that though. Someone suggested a Poisson regression, but I believe that assumes that the variance and mean are equal, which is not the case with this data.

Any ideas on an appropriate analysis?

Comment: Why does a low pseudo-$R^2$ make you think the model is poor?  What do you mean by "pseudo-$R^2$", anyway? Also, are you sure you want to model trials as nested within groups? Your description makes it sound like, e.g., trial 4 is the same trial for both groups.

Comment: Sorry, the R2 is actually 0.002. Accounting for 0.2% of the variance seems like a negligible amount. [This is what I mean by "pseudo-R2"](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/). 

I'm not nesting trial within group, that model expands to `choose_true ~ group + (1 + group | trial)`, which is saying that there's a random intercept for trial and a random slope of group for trial.

Comment: That pages lists several different notions of pseudo-$R^2$. But in any case, the mere fact that a model doesn't account for much variance doesn't imply that the model is incorrect, or bad for your purposes. Maybe it's just that the group and trial type aren't strongly related to the outcome.